# Why simulink step response differs from matlab's step function?

Tags: control, matlab, stability, simulink

step response is different in simulink showing oscillatory behavior unlike in matlab step function

Transfer function

[image]

Step response

[image]

Block diagram in simulink

[image]

Simulink scope

[image]

Comment: You're doing something wrong in Simulink.  The transfer function has a pair of complex poles, and DC response is 6.49E-3, so you would expect something exactly like Matlab is showing.

Comment: Have you tried actually putting a step into the filter (aka multiplying the denominator by s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a numeric issue caused by the simulation step size. The system poles have real parts in -0.4e6, and as can be seen in the matlab 'step()' result, the settling time is lower than 2e-5.

Using simulink default simulation parameters, the system response will be evaluated in time-steps that are larger than what is necessary to describe what is really going on, similar to a Nyquist sampling criteria.

To get correct simulation results with your system, I've done the following:

1. Open the 'Model Configuration Parameters' (cog icon);
2. Change 'Stop Time' to 2e-5;
3. In 'Solver Options', change 'Type' to 'Fixed-step' and 'Solver' to 'ode8 (Dormand-Prince)';
4. In 'Additional options', change 'Fixed-step size (fundamental sample time)' to 1e-7.

Now the simulation runs as expected. Proof:

[image]

Comment: i tried it and it works but based on what did you choose those values ?!

Comment: Total time was chosen as 2e-5 because it is enough to simulate the transient response of this system. Fixed-step size was chosen to be 2 orders of magnitude lower than total time, essentially making simulink evaluate the system 1600 times in the total simulation time. We've also chosen ode8 that subdivides the fundamental sample time (8*2e-5/1e-7).